# Filling NaN values with values that are not NaN using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that have 2 columns with some NaN values in both columns.

```
df = { 'A' : [1,Nan, 2, Nan, Nan, 3],
       'B' : [Nan, Nan, 3, 4, 5 ,Nan]}
```

I would like to fill NaN values in column A with only not NaN values in column B and vice versa.
The result should be like:

```
df = { 'A': [1,Nan, 2, 4, 5, 3],
       'B' : [1, Nan, 3, 4, 5 ,3]}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, `bfill` and `ffill` with `axis` parameter equal to 1:

```
df.ffill(1).bfill(1)
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  2.0  3.0
3  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  3.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `df.fillna`

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = { 'A' : [1,np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3],
       'B' : [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5 ,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df["A"] = df["A"].fillna(df["B"])
df["B"] = df["B"].fillna(df["A"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     A    B
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  2.0  3.0
3  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  3.0  3.0
```